# Why is the page not refreshing after 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php

This is an include page, why is it not refreshing automatically after 10 seconds , since I put the correct code in the top of the script. I have tied javascript, ajax, jquery codes and still the same result, no refreshing?

```
<?php header('Refresh: 10'); ?>
<div class="span3">
   <div class="sidebar">
      <ul class="widget widget-menu unstyled">
      <li>
         <a id="coll" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#togglePages">
         <i class="menu-icon icon-cog"></i>
         <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right"></i><i class="icon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
         Order Management
         <?php
            $status='Delivered';                                     
            $ret1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Orders where orderStatus!='$status' || orderStatus is null ");
            $num1 = mysqli_num_rows($ret1);
            ?>
         <b id="bell" class="label orange pull-right"><?php echo htmlentities($num1);?></b>
         </a>
   </div>
   <!--/.sidebar-->
</div>
<!--/.span3-->
```

Please any help

Comment: Are you sure you do not send any additional output before you set the header? The snippet you provide actually works and refreshes every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

According to php docs:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

[source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Maybe you can try with js:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
</script>
```